# DataType Data Annotation

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, c#-4.0, data-annotations

Since every property in class has DataType what is need for `DataType` in data annotation?

thanks

Comment: Did you read the [msdn definition and remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataType` attribute is for marking the "real" data type for the property.
For example, a property typed `string` can be a `DataType.PhoneNumber` or a comment to a post (`DataType.MultilineText`).

Comment: So 'DataType.PhoneNumber' is string isn't it?Again I don't know what is usage of that.If we set DataType to 'DataType.PhoneNumber' c# does not validate any thing

Comment: It provides additional information of the property. Although the extra info can't be validated by the C# compiler, it is useful in other scenarios. For example, a ASP.NET MVC Helper function can use it to generate suitable `<input/>` elements in a form, and may apply JS validation according to the `DataType`.